# How to put comma separated values to a column in oracle

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql

I have a JSON response and after processing the response my output looks like this :

```
column_variable := 'col1,col2,col3';
data_clob := 
"2017-10-14,abc,1,
2019-10-13,abc,12,
2019-10-12,abc,,
"
;
```

as the original response was having escape characters for `new line` ,`data_clob` also has been converted accordingly .

How do I convert this comma separated values in oracle table :

My output should look like this :

```
col1            col2     col3 
2017-10-14      abc      1
2019-10-13      abc      12
2019-10-12      abc      null
```

I was looking through similar questions ,but I dont want to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` as I dont know the number of columns I will get in the response .
for e.g : `column_variable` might have `'col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6'`;

I am using `oracle 12.1.0.2.0`

Please help !

Comment: Could you also show the original JSON response in the question ? Perhaps it will be easier to parse data directly from JSON?

Comment: Hi Krokodilko ..Just added the original JSON response in question

Comment: This JSON has a bad structure, it would be better and easier if it looked like this: `data: [ {"col1":"2017-10-14","col2":"abc","col3":1}, {"col1":"2019-10-13","col2":"abc","col3":12}, {"col1":"2019-10-12","col2":"abc"} ]`. Maybe the author of this API could change the format of the response?

Comment: Yes ,I agree it has a bad structure ,but I have no control to change it

Comment: So, you expect us to simply write a query/procedure to *magically* transform your data and give a database `Table` for you without previously knowing anything about datatype,number of columns the table will contain etc?

Comment: @KaushikNayak I was trying to process the csv data , as all other questions mostly has regexp_substr to process csv data , I was looking for other ways to do it,in case anyone knows about any library etc

Answer (score 1):

There is very easy way to achieve it using `Polymorphic Table Functions` (Oracle 18c):

[Dynamic CSV to Columns Converter: Polymorphic Table Function Example](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_F99JG73Z169WENDTTQFDQ0J09.html):

```
create or replace package csv_pkg as  
  /* The describe function defines the new columns */  
  function describe (  
    tab in out dbms_tf.table_t,  
    col_names varchar2  
  ) return dbms_tf.describe_t;  

  /* Fetch_rows sets the values for the new columns */  
  procedure fetch_rows (col_names varchar2);  
end csv_pkg;
```

and body:

```
create or replace package body csv_pkg as  
  function describe(  
    tab in out dbms_tf.table_t,  
    col_names varchar2  
  )   
    return dbms_tf.describe_t as  
    new_cols dbms_tf.columns_new_t;  
    col_id   pls_integer := 2;  
  begin   

    /* Enable the source colun for reading */  
    tab.column(1).pass_through := FALSE;  
    tab.column(1).for_read     := TRUE;  
    new_cols(1) := tab.column(1).description;  

    /* Extract the column names from the header string,  
       creating a new column for each   
     */  
    for j in 1 .. ( length(col_names) - length(replace(col_names,',')) ) + 1 loop   
      new_cols(col_id) := dbms_tf.column_metadata_t(  
        name=>regexp_substr(col_names, '[^,]+', 1, j),--'c'||j,   
        type=>dbms_tf.type_varchar2  
      );  
      col_id := col_id + 1;  
    end loop;  

    return dbms_tf.describe_t( new_columns => new_cols );  
  end;  

  procedure fetch_rows (col_names varchar2) as   
    rowset    dbms_tf.row_set_t;  
    row_count pls_integer;  
  begin  
    /* read the input data set */  
    dbms_tf.get_row_set(rowset, row_count => row_count);  

    /* Loop through the input rows... */  
    for i in 1 .. row_count loop  
      /* ...and the defined columns, extracting the relevant value   
         start from 2 to skip the input string  
      */  
      for j in 2 .. ( length(col_names) - length(replace(col_names,',')) ) + 2 loop  
        rowset(j).tab_varchar2(i) :=   
          regexp_substr(rowset(1).tab_varchar2(i), '[^,]+', 1, j - 1);  
      end loop;  
    end loop;  

    /* Output the new columns and their values */  
    dbms_tf.put_row_set(rowset);  

  end;  

end csv_pkg;  

--function
create or replace function csv_to_columns(  
  tab table, col_names varchar2  
) return table pipelined row polymorphic using csv_pkg;
```

Then you simply pass:

```
select *   
from   csv_to_columns( data_clob, column_variable );
```

Comment: Hi lad2025 , thanks for the answer! you know if something similar is available for oracle 12.1.0.2.0

Comment: @joe Probably you need to write custom one.

Comment: Oracle 18c? Welcome time-traveler! ;-)

Comment: @DavidFaber Yes, **[Oracle 18c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/index.html)**. The future is now :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution for Oracle versions below 18 and maybe 12, not sure... This is not perfect and will create an empty column at the end based on data you provided - extra spaces, commas, etc... This may also create a blank space between the 'SELECT' and the first column in output. All that can be removed later manually or with more coding. I hope this helps, at least in some ways:

```
SELECT 'SELECT '''||REPLACE(str, chr(10), ''' FROM dual'||chr(10)||'UNION ALL'||chr(10)||'SELECT ''')||''' FROM dual' str
  FROM
  (
   SELECT TRIM(REPLACE(str, ',', ''''||', ''')) str FROM
   (
    SELECT TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM
     '"2017-10-14,abc,1,
       2019-10-13,abc,12,
       2019-10-12,abc,,"') AS str FROM dual
   )
  )
/
```

This will build the select statement that can be cleaned up and executed manually or with dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT '2017-10-14' col, 'abc' col, '1' col, '' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '2019-10-13' col, 'abc' col, '12' col, '' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT '2019-10-12' col, 'abc' col, '' col, ''  FROM dual
```

The output of the above select statement:

```
COL         COL_1   COL_2
2017-10-14  abc         1
2019-10-13  abc        12
2019-10-12  abc      null
```